# How to select one row with longest sentence for a particular column and merge to form a new dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The dataset I am using looks like this. It is a video captioning data set with captions under the column 'Description'.

```
Video_ID       Description
mv89psg6zh4    A bird is bathing in a sink.
mv89psg6zh4    A faucet is running while a bird stands and is taking bath under it.
mv89psg6zh4    A bird gets washed.
mv89psg6zh4    A parakeet is taking a shower in a sink.
mv89psg6zh4    The bird is taking a bath under the faucet.
mv89psg6zh4    A bird is standing in a sink drinking water.
l7x8uIdg2XU    A woman is pouring ingredients into a bowl and then eating it.
l7x8uIdg2XU    A woman is adding milk to some pasta.
l7x8uIdg2XU    A person adds ingredients to pasta. 
l7x8uIdg2XU    the girls are doing the cooking.
```

However, the number of captions for each video is different and not uniform.

I intend to extract one row which has the longest "Description" (that is with the maximum number of words) for one unique Video_ID and form a new dataframe merging these unique rows.

The result I want should look like this:

Dataframe Needed-

```
Video_ID       Description
mv89psg6zh4    A faucet is running while a bird stands and is taking bath under it.
l7x8uIdg2XU    A woman is pouring ingredients into a bowl and then eating it.
```

So that the rows are basically moved from the existing dataframe to form a new dataframe which contains the longest sentences from the original dataset.

I tried to use the following code:

```
s = df.index.to_series().groupby(df['Video_ID']).apply(lambda x: len(x['Description']).max())
```

But this does not seem to work. Can you suggest the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) for lengths and then get index values by maximal per groups by [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) and last select by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df1 = df.loc[df['Description'].str.len().groupby(df['Video_ID'], sort=False).idxmax()]
print (df1)
      Video_ID                                        Description
1  mv89psg6zh4  A faucet is running while a bird stands and is...
6  l7x8uIdg2XU  A woman is pouring ingredients into a bowl and...
```

**Details**:

```
print (df['Description'].str.len())
0    28
1    68
2    19
3    40
4    43
5    44
6    62
7    37
8    35
9    32
Name: Description, dtype: int64

print (df['Description'].str.len().groupby(df['Video_ID'], sort=False).idxmax())
Video_ID
mv89psg6zh4    1
l7x8uIdg2XU    6
Name: Description, dtype: int64
```

For filter not matched rows is possible use [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) with inverted mask `~` and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df2 = df[~df.index.isin(df1.index)]
print (df2)
      Video_ID                                   Description
0  mv89psg6zh4                  A bird is bathing in a sink.
2  mv89psg6zh4                           A bird gets washed.
3  mv89psg6zh4      A parakeet is taking a shower in a sink.
4  mv89psg6zh4   The bird is taking a bath under the faucet.
5  mv89psg6zh4  A bird is standing in a sink drinking water.
7  l7x8uIdg2XU         A woman is adding milk to some pasta.
8  l7x8uIdg2XU           A person adds ingredients to pasta.
9  l7x8uIdg2XU              the girls are doing the cooking.
```

EDIT: Solution above return only one row of maximal length per groups. (Here is working same, because only one maximal length per groups in sample data)

If want multiple maximal per groups is possible comapre maximal length in [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
s = df['Description'].str.len()
mask = s.groupby(df['Video_ID'], sort=False).transform('max').eq(s)
df1 = df[mask]
print (df1)
      Video_ID                                        Description
1  mv89psg6zh4  A faucet is running while a bird stands and is...
6  l7x8uIdg2XU  A woman is pouring ingredients into a bowl and...

df2 = df[~mask]
print (df2)
      Video_ID                                   Description
0  mv89psg6zh4                  A bird is bathing in a sink.
2  mv89psg6zh4                           A bird gets washed.
3  mv89psg6zh4      A parakeet is taking a shower in a sink.
4  mv89psg6zh4   The bird is taking a bath under the faucet.
5  mv89psg6zh4  A bird is standing in a sink drinking water.
7  l7x8uIdg2XU         A woman is adding milk to some pasta.
8  l7x8uIdg2XU           A person adds ingredients to pasta.
9  l7x8uIdg2XU              the girls are doing the cooking.
```

Details:

```
print (s.groupby(df['Video_ID'], sort=False).transform('max'))
0    68
1    68
2    68
3    68
4    68
5    68
6    62
7    62
8    62
9    62
Name: Description, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you, this works fine. Is there a way to extract the remaining rows into another dataframe? This one is not 'subscriptable'.